# Microsoft Access Multiple Criteria based on another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working with a database in MS Access.
I have a table(Table A) with different categories (criteria)
I have another table (Table B), where I have to pull values from Table A based on two categories, (year and amount).
For example, 
From table B, the cost is $15,000, so we go to table A and find the contingency from year 2018 which falls between $0-$20,000 and report a contingency of 25%.

Is there a way to go about this? I've been racking my brain trying to use nested  "IIF" and "AND" functions but i can't figure it out

[image: Table A]

[image: Table B]

Comment: Please post the actual table structures, some sample data and the query(s) you tried and the output you expect.

Comment: Terry, I posted the table structures and sample data below my post as pictures, unless you cannot see the pictures I tagged as Table A and Table B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add both tables to a query.
Join on C_YEAR.
Use BETWEEN AND to grab the appropriate range hence the appropriate contingency.
Something like:

```
SELECT tableA.CONTINGENCY
FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.C_YEAR = tableB.C_YEAR
WHERE tableB.COST BETWEEN tableA.MIN_VALUE AND tableA.MAX_VALUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the contingency rates for all the years are the same:

- 25% for values between $0 and $20,000
- 15% for values between $20,001 and $200,000
- 10% for values between $200,000 and $100,000

Is this always the case, or just based on the sample data you're using?

Is it possible you'll have data where the cost is > $100,000,000? If so, how should the data be handled?

I'm just wondering if there's not a better way to represent your contingency rate rules. Otherwise, I'd agree with Rene about joining the tables and adding a `WHERE` condition to get the rates you need. I'd also add that, since you'll always be pulling the rate from the query, you don't need an actual field on `Table B` to store the contingency rate.

Comment: Right now the contingency rates are the same. But possibly they could change in the future. And no, no costs will be above $100,000,000.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a `DLookUp` in an `UPDATE` query. The domain aggregate is needed for query to be updateable.

```
UPDATE tableB b
SET b.Contingency = DLookUp("CONTINGENCY", "tableA", "[C_YEAR] = " & b.[C_YEAR] &
                            " AND [MIN_VALUE] <= " & b.[COST] & " AND [MAX_VALUE] >= " &  b.[Cost])
```